# Send new user a custom messages?

Tags: moodle

I want to writ a module(plugin) for Moodle to send new users some messages.

but I don't know how to hook in signup action.

pleas help me?

Comment: How are you signin up users? Are you want to rebuild the whole method or you just want to hook the signip process to send a messege?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that I don't need to hook to user creation.
just add a listener to user_created event
for more information see this: 
[Events API](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API#Users)